# My phone always loses connection with Android Device Chooser and says it's unknown/offline

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure why, but my phone always loses the connection with the Android Virtual Device manager when I plug it in. Initially, it recognizes my phone, but after around 10 seconds or so it loses connection and says it's offline and unknown.

What I see when I plug it in initially is on the right, and the left shows what I see when I wait about 10 seconds or so (not even long enough to install my app). Any ideas?

P.S. When I first plug it in, it says "Connected as an installer" in my notification area, but after a little while it says "Connected as a media device." I have a feeling something here is the culprit, but can't figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Change your cable and then try again.

Comment: Have you updated your SDK to latest?